# Span element doesn't show specific variables coming from NodeMCU devices

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, arduino

I'm looking to make a FireBase website which will print sensor readings coming from 3 NodeMCU devices. To make the text look better I utilized span elements in order to specifically customize the reading font and color. The problem is whenever I load the site, nothing shows up at all.

Here is the index.html code for loading the website (ID's and security related parameters have been removed so there will be a couple of empty strings):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Monitoring</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.1/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.1/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <script>
    // REPLACE WITH YOUR web app's Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    var database = firebase.database();
</script>


</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Live data feed:</h1> 
    <p class="content-text">Bedroom 1 Temperature: <span class="bedroom1-temp" id="bedroom1-temp"></span></p>
    <p class="content-text">Bedroom 1 Humidity: <span class="bedroom1-hum" id="bedroom1-hum"></span></p>
    <p class="content-text">Bedroom 2 Temperature: <span class="bedroom2-temp" id="bedroom2-temp"></span></p>
    <p class="content-text">Bedroom 2 Humidity: <span class="bedroom2-hum" id="bedroom2-hum"></span></p>
    <p class="content-text">Bathroom Temperature: <span class="bathroom-temp" id="bathroom-temp"></span></p>
    <p class="content-text">Bathroom Humidity: <span class="bathroom-hum" id="bathroom-hum"></span></p>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the app.js script which initializes some reference variables which should attach themselves to the span elements. Those are the sensor readings:

```
// Database Paths
var dataBedroom1TemperaturePath = "/test/bedroom1temperature";
var dataBedroom2TemperaturePath = "/test/bedroom2temperature";
var dataBathroomTemperaturePath = "/test/bathroomtemperature";

var dataBedroom1HumidityPath = "/test/bedroom1humidity";
var dataBedroom2HumidityPath = "/test/bedroom2humidity";
var dataBathroomHumidityPath = "/test/bathroomhumidity";


// Get a database reference 
const dataBedroom1TempReading = database.ref(dataBedroom1TemperaturePath);
const dataBedroom2TempReading = database.ref(dataBedroom2TemperaturePath);
const dataBathroomTempReading = database.ref(dataBathroomTemperaturePath);

const dataBedroom1HumReading = database.ref(dataBedroom1HumidityPath);
const dataBedroom2HumReading = database.ref(dataBedroom2HumidityPath);
const dataBathroomHumReading = database.ref(dataBathroomHumidityPath);


// Variables to save database current values
var floatBedroom1TempReading;
var floatBedroom2TempReading;
var floatBathroomTempReading;

var floatBedroom1HumReading;
var floatBedroom2HumReading;
var floatBathroomHumReading;


// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data

//BEDROOM 1

dataBedroom1TempReading.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  floatBedroom1TempReading = snapshot.val();
  console.log(floatBedroom1TempReading);
  document.getElementById("bedroom1-temp").innerHTML = floatBedroom1TempReading;
}, (errorObject) => {
  console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
});

dataBedroom1HumReading.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  floatBedroom1HumReading = snapshot.val();
  console.log(floatBedroom1HumReading);
  document.getElementById("bedroom1-hum").innerHTML = floatBedroom1HumReading;
}, (errorObject) => {
  console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
});

//BEDROOM 2

dataBedroom2TempReading.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  floatBedroom2TempReading = snapshot.val();
  console.log(floatBedroom2TempReading);
  document.getElementById("bedroom2-temp").innerHTML = floatBedroom2TempReading;
}, (errorObject) => {
  console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
});

dataBedroom2HumReading.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  floatBedroom2HumReading = snapshot.val();
  console.log(floatBedroom2HumReading);
  document.getElementById("bedroom2-hum").innerHTML = floatBedroom2HumReading;
}, (errorObject) => {
  console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
});

//BATHROOM

dataBathroomTempReading.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  floatBathroomTempReading = snapshot.val();
  console.log(floatBathroomTempReading);
  document.getElementById("bathroom-temp").innerHTML = floatBathroomTempReading;
}, (errorObject) => {
  console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
});

dataBathroomHumReading.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  floatBathroomHumReading = snapshot.val();
  console.log(floatBathroomHumReading);
  document.getElementById("bathroom-hum").innerHTML = floatBathroomHumReading;
}, (errorObject) => {
  console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
});
```

When I load the page, the [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyumb.png) shows 6 items with no content at all. However the innerHTML property is not null since there are no errors.

In this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IacJN.png) the website is shown but as presented there are no readings received.

If anyone needs the nodeMCU code for reference, it is down below:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <espnow.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Firebase_ESP_Client.h>
#include "addons/TokenHelper.h"
#include "addons/RTDBHelper.h"

//#define WIFI_SSID ""
//#define WIFI_PASSWORD ""

#define WIFI_SSID ""
#define WIFI_PASSWORD ""

#define API_KEY ""
#define DATABASE_URL ""

FirebaseData fbdo;

FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseConfig config;

bool signupOK = false;

String incomingData;
char serialData;

String gateway_temperature;
String gateway_humidity;
String gateway_gas;

SoftwareSerial ESPserial(4, 5); // RX, TX

//#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
//#include <DHT.h>

// REPLACE WITH THE MAC Address of your receiver 
// this is the receiver

// Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor
#define DHTPIN 2    

// Uncomment the type of sensor in use:
//#define DHTTYPE    DHT11     // DHT 11
//#define DHTTYPE    DHT22     // DHT 22 (AM2302)
//#define DHTTYPE    DHT21     // DHT 21 (AM2301)

//DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

// Define variables to store DHT readings to be sent
//float temperature;
//float humidity;

// Define variables to store incoming readings
//float incomingTemp_D98F;
//float incomingHum_D98F;
//float incomingTemp_A942;
//float incomingHum_A942;
//float incomingTemp_15B5;
//float incomingHum_15B5;

// Updates DHT readings every 30 seconds
const long interval = 30000; 
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;    // will store last time DHT was updated 

// Variable to store if sending data was successful
//String success;

//Structure example to send data
//Must match the receiver structure
//typedef struct struct_message {
//    float temp;
//    float hum;
//} struct_message;
//

typedef struct Data{
  int id;
  float temperature;
  float humidity;
} Data;

Data myData;

Data nodeMCU_D98F;
Data nodeMCU_A942;
Data nodeMCU_15B5;

Data nodeMCUStruct[3] = {nodeMCU_D98F, nodeMCU_A942, nodeMCU_15B5};

String str;

// Callback when data is sent
//void OnDataSent(uint8_t *mac_addr, uint8_t sendStatus) {
//  Serial.print("Last Packet Send Status: ");
//  if (sendStatus == 0){
//    Serial.println("Delivery success");
//  }
//  else{
//    Serial.println("Delivery fail");
//  }
//}

// Callback when data is received
void OnDataRecv(uint8_t * mac, uint8_t *incomingData, uint8_t len) {
  char macStr[18];
  //Serial.print("Packet received from: ");
  //snprintf(macStr, sizeof(macStr), "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", 
  //mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
  //Serial.println(macStr);
  
  memcpy(&myData, incomingData, sizeof(myData));
  nodeMCUStruct[myData.id-1].temperature = myData.temperature;
  nodeMCUStruct[myData.id-1].humidity = myData.humidity;
}

//void getReadings(){
//  // Read Temperature
//  temperature = dht.readTemperature();
//  // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
//  //float t = dht.readTemperature(true);
//  if (isnan(temperature)){
//    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
//    temperature = 0.0;
//  }
//  humidity = dht.readHumidity();
//  if (isnan(humidity)){
//    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
//    humidity = 0.0;
//  }
//}

void printIncomingReadings(){
  
  Serial.println(nodeMCUStruct[0].temperature);
  Serial.println(nodeMCUStruct[0].humidity);
  Serial.println(nodeMCUStruct[1].temperature);
  Serial.println(nodeMCUStruct[1].humidity);
  Serial.println(nodeMCUStruct[2].temperature);
  Serial.println(nodeMCUStruct[2].humidity);
  ESPserial.println(nodeMCUStruct[0].temperature);
  ESPserial.println(nodeMCUStruct[0].humidity); 
  ESPserial.println(nodeMCUStruct[1].temperature);
  ESPserial.println(nodeMCUStruct[1].humidity);
  ESPserial.println(nodeMCUStruct[2].temperature);
  ESPserial.println(nodeMCUStruct[2].humidity);
  Serial.print("Wi-Fi Channel: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.channel());
}
 
void setup() {
  // Init Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ESPserial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  // Init DHT sensor
  //dht.begin();
 
  // Set device as a Wi-Fi Station
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  //WiFi.disconnect();

  // Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != 0) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }

  // Set ESP-NOW Role
  esp_now_set_self_role(ESP_NOW_ROLE_COMBO);

  // Once ESPNow is successfully Init, we will register for Send CB to
  // get the status of Trasnmitted packet
  //esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);
  
  // Register peer
  //esp_now_add_peer(broadcastAddress, ESP_NOW_ROLE_COMBO, 1, NULL, 0);
  
  // Register for a callback function that will be called when data is received
  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);

  Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();

  auth.user.email = "esp8266@gmail.com";
  auth.user.password = "Tintenpatronen1&";

  /* Assign the api key (required) */
  config.api_key = API_KEY;

  /* Assign the RTDB URL (required) */
  config.database_url = DATABASE_URL;

  /* Sign up */
  if (Firebase.signUp(&config, &auth, "", "")){
    Serial.println("ok");
    signupOK = true;
  }
  else{
    Serial.printf("%s\n", config.signer.signupError.message.c_str());
  }

  /* Assign the callback function for the long running token generation task */
  config.token_status_callback = tokenStatusCallback; //see addons/TokenHelper.h
  
  Firebase.begin(&config, &auth);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
}
 
void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  
  printIncomingReadings();
  
  if (Firebase.ready() && signupOK && Firebase.authenticated())
  {
//    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, "/test/kitchentemperature",atof(gateway_temperature));
//    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, "/test/kitchenhumidity",atof(gateway_humidity));
//    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, "/test/kitchenGAS",atof(gateway_gas));
    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, "/test/bedroom1temperature",nodeMCUStruct[0].temperature);
    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, "/test/bedroom1humidity",nodeMCUStruct[0].humidity);
    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, "/test/bedroom2temperature",nodeMCUStruct[1].temperature);
    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, "/test/bedroom2humidity",nodeMCUStruct[1].humidity);
    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, "/test/bathroomtemperature",nodeMCUStruct[2].temperature);
    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, "/test/bathroomhumidity",nodeMCUStruct[2].humidity);
  }
  
  
  
  delay(30000);
}
```

I must mention the nodeMCU code works just fine, it receives the data and prints it in the console as expected. The only issue is whether the firebase callback functions do in fact send the items in the realtime database, or there is just an exclusive issue with my javascript/html code.

My approaches included: placing the app.js script at the end of the body tag in index.html, changing span ID, removing the class from the span elements, refreshing/redeploying the website. The effect only removed the previous errors "Cannot set property to innerHTML null"